# Unable to grep sourced Files in Vim

Tags: grep, vim

I have files which I source in my files.
I want to search them, when I am at a file which have these sources.

I run unsuccessfully

```
!bufdo grep source
```

and

```
!bufdo grep source %
```

---

**Example of .zshrc which sourced PATHs I want to grep**

```
# ~/bin/shells/Zsh/describtion
# ~/bin/shells/Zsh/bugs
# ./bin/shells/zsh/alphaOptions

. /Users/masi/bin/shells/.personal/ssh
. /Users/masi/bin/shells/.personal/shellVariables
. /Users/masi/bin/shells/.personal/alias

. /Users/masi/bin/shells/externalPrograms

. /Users/masi/bin/shells/codingSettings

# . /Users/masi/bin/shells/OS/ubuntu/alias

# ~/bin/shells/Zsh/sources
```

Let's assume you are at my .zshrc. You want to search the word "manual" in all sourced files in Vim.

**How would you search the word manual in only the sourced files?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
:! grep manual `sed -n 's/^\. \(.*\)/\1/p' %`
```

The sed part looks for source files and gives them as arguments to grep.

To avoid having to type this everytime you can create a command like this:

```
:command! -nargs=1 SourceGrep :! grep <args> `sed -n 's/^\. \(.*\)/\1/p' %`
```

Be careful when searching for more than one word, you'll have to use quotes. For example:

```
:SourceGrep "sudo ssh"
```

**EDIT:**

To search for lines with 'source' as well as '.':

```
:! grep manual `sed -rn 's/^(\.|source) (.*)/\2/p' %`
```

The command will look like this:

```
:command! -nargs=1 SourceGrep :! grep <args> `sed -rn 's/^(source|\.) (.*)/\2/p' %`
```

Comment: Does the code "'s/^\. \(.*\)/\1/p" mean #1. find the start of a line which has a dot and a [space]+word after that #2. replace the match with the the reference to the first parameter (\1)?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. The '-n' tells sed only to output what's explicitly stated by the p command.

Comment: I use also the word "source". I need OR -operator for SED. I did not find one for SED. I run too unsuccessfully: % sed 's/sa\|he/x/g' %

Comment: I updated my answer to look for source lines as well

Comment: @chmeee: Thank you for your answers! --- I noticed that Vim's ex -mode has a different syntax than Sed: you need to escape the brackets in Vim, while in SED, you do not need to.

Comment: <args> seems to be the part of the code wihch puts the parameters after SourceGrep to the command in ":" -mode.

Comment: Yes, look for '40.2  Defining command-line commands' in vim :help for information bout creating new commands

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to run external command from vim and pass it the content of the file you are currently editing, you can use something like this:

:!grep sometext %

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your .zshrc file open, and you want to grep something in all of the files source in it. You can do this from vim like this:

```
!sed -ne 's/^\. \(.*\)/\1/gp' % | xargs grep foobar
```

Replace "foobar" with whatever it is you want to grep.

Comment: @Evgeny: Does the percent sign % after the "sed" means: apply the sed command to all lines of the file?

Comment: No, the % gets substituded with the file name vim is editing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main file is called 'mainfile', you can run something like:

```
$ grep searchstring mainfile $(grep source mainfile | awk '{print $2}')
```

(I assumed you use `source <file>` inside your mainfile for sourcing)

Update: See an example:

```
$ head a b c
==> a <==
afile
source b
source c

==> b <==
bfile

==> c <==
cfile

$ grep file a $(grep source a | awk '{print $2}')
a:afile
b:bfile
c:cfile
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean the following: !grep source * `(grep source * | awk '{ print }')` . I run it unsuccessfully.

Comment: I am sorry, my response was for shell commands. I assume you can use that as a base for something to run from vi though. I added an example to my response.